# Angular ng serve da este error Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "/scripts/2" must be object

Tags: angular

le consulto por si alguien me puede indicar sobre este inconveniente, mucha gracias

```
 Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
   Data path "/scripts/2" must be object.
   Data path "/scripts/2" must match pattern "\.[cm]?jsx?$".
   Data path "/scripts/2" must match exactly one schema in oneOf.
```

Es un proyecto en angular 14.1.1 al correr ng serve.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser un error en tu `package.json`. Tendrías que revisar si la versión de Angular que se muestra en el archivo es la que estás utilizando, en mi caso (yo que utilizo angular 14), lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.1.4",
```

También podrías borrar la carpeta `node modules` y volverlo a instalar con `npm install`.

Comment: Hola, si, node modules ya lo borre y volvi a instalar. Habia leido algo de las versiones, se tengo una versión de angular cli global tambien 14 pero un poco superior.   Yo lo tengo asi "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.1.1", será que tengo que editar este último así: @angular/cli": "^14.1.1", ? . O bien ambas "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.1.1", voy a probar. Gracias

Comment: Vale me avisa si le funcionó.

Comment: Hola, no funcionó, tenia una copia, una versíon reciente, seguí con esa.  Actualicé los cambios nuevos y no insistí. Gracias